# Lumber Mills in Ancient Forests, Desecration or Good Resource Management?

Tags: mods, civilization-4, fall-from-heaven-2

In Fall From Heave 2 you have ancient forests as well as normal forests.  Ancient forests are better, providing an extra food.  In both Civ 4 and Fall From Heaven there are lumber mill that can be built in forests providing one production and leaving the forest.

**Is there any disadvantage to building a lumber mill in an Ancient Forest?**  Is there any penalty as follower of the nature religion for doing so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you can't build lumber mills on Ancient Forests.

To quote [Kael](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showpost.php?p=5890393&postcount=5468)

> Partially roleplaying (we didnt like that the nature worshipping religion was able to chop down trees) but it was a balance decision as well. Ancient forests are already pretty cool, they would be to good if you could also drop a lumbermill on the tile and we didn't want the Fellowship to be an economic powerhouse.

Comment: Apparently you can have this if the lumber mill was there first.  I found this as I used culture to take tiles with lumber mills, and of course my culture caused those forests to become ancient.

Comment: @Cross Yes. You can't build a lumber mill on an Ancient Forest, but a forest with a lumber mill can become one.